# How to use Infovis Library in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infovis

I want to use Infovis library in my Web Application using Reactjs. But I cant able to find any documentation or example in google. How to use these examples [infovis toolkit](https://philogb.github.io/jit)  in ReactJS?

Comment: only demos are there

Comment: Docs are there => https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Core/Core-js.html

Comment: Yeah I have seen that, but I would like to know how to use that library in react.